# Cannot convert a string field to a number field

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a database field that gives me +ve and -ve numbers.

I am using `toNumber({table.fieldName})` to convert it to a number and use in calculations in Crystal Reports but the problem is that if the number is +ve it is converted to a number and calculations are performed successfully but if the number is -ve i.e -11, -44 etc the field shows ######## and the fields that perform calculations on it as well shows ######

I've tried using the `if (isNumber({table.fieldName)))` then `toNumber({table.fieldName})` but it gives me an error saying a string is required here.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the filed as below. Here you have options which will display the negative numbers correctly.

[image]

Comment: That's not exactly what I am looking for, let's say the string field contains 10 it works fine when I use toNumber(10) but when I do toNumber(-10) it shows me #####